# How to crop the photo or resize accordingly to its container UIImage View?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage, swift3, xcode8

So I programmatically assigned the last two images in my collection view cell which contains an image view. But it was not the right size.

[image]

This is my code:

```
let groupImage = self.groupImage[customImageIndex]
cell.groupImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
cell.groupImage.image = groupImage
```

It should appear like the one on the Work Collection View Cell.

Answer (score 1):

use

`cell.groupImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill` or

```
cell.groupImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
```

not

```
cell.groupImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```